# How can I delete the Extjs4 Drag&Drop Proxy?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How can i hide the D&D Proxy? (Proxy? Shadow?)

I used .hideproxy() but, NOT..

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the Ghost (The shadow that appears when you move/drag objects), you can hide them with CSS like this: (Simple Approach)

```
.x-dd-drag-ghost,
.x-panel-ghost,
.x-window-ghost {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE 5-7 */
    -moz-opacity: 0; /* Netscape */
    -khtml-opacity: 0; /* Safari 1.x */
    opacity: 0; /* Good browsers */
}
```